# System.Data.SqlClient fails when SQL Server Management Studio succeeds

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I expect discussions to be more speculative than definitive, because the issue is rather speculative itself. It is rather confounding in nature.

I'm looking at .NET 4.0 C# code that utilizes `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary` for SQL Server data access.

The code calls a stored procedure which runs well in SQL Server Management Studio and returns results. The problem is, when the procedure is called in from the C# side, an exception is thrown.

The offending code is as follows:

```
Database _db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(instance_name);
string _sql = "[dbo].[usp_stored_procedure]";
DbCommand _cmd = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(_sql);
/* _db.AddInParameter calls to supply parameters */
DataSet _ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(_cmd);
```

The last line throws an exception, that says:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   ....
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
>   ....
>   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
>   ....
>   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteDataSet(DbCommand command)
>
> ....
>   at DataAccess.call_stored_procedure (string instance_name, int? _client_id, int? _client_group_id, int? _event_type_id, DateTime _start_date, DateTime _end_date, int? _employee_type_id, int? _survey_id, int? _ro_date )

I've omitted (what I amass to be) unnecessary stack trace, and the function in which the exception is thrown. The arguments are supplied in that order, and the types match precisely.

There are usages of `Decimal(18, 10)` in the stored procedure, and the stored procedure works with a previous set of data (and on C# side as well) It creates problem with the new supply of data.

My "question" is if this sort of behavior is a known issue, or where to start looking. It seems bizarre that what works in SQL Server Management Studio does not in C# code invocation.

Comment: This isn't a SQL Server related error, it's indicating that the value returned from the database can't be marshaled into the .NET data type you're using in the DataSet.

Comment: You should attach SQL Profiler and see if the code is executing the SQL statement you assume it is.

Comment: check the datatype of the table schema, and then compare it against the data type of the values you are passing or trying to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

maybe you add parameters in incorrect type
you should tel us about type of field in sql and add parameters in your codw